# ZF2 directory structure for lots of applications

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, directory, structure

I'm learning ZF2 and I need some help. I am working in a company which has an intranet. We have lots of applications like newsletter, HR, website control, helpdesk, etc.
Is it correct to put all the applications in the same ZF2 directory structure as if they were modules? Like this:

```
intranet/
    /config
    /data
    /module
        /helpdesk
            /config
            /src
            /view                        
        /HR
            /config
            /src
            /view
         /newletter
            /config
            /src
            /view
```

Or it would be better if I put each application in a separated skeleton structure?

```
intranet/
    /helpdesk
        /config
        /data
        /module
        /public
        /vendor
    /HR
        /config
        /data
        /module
        /public
        /vendor
    /newsletter
        /config
        /data
        /module
        /public
        /vendor
```

The applications need to interact with each other, exchange data etc.

Comment: I think the first structure is more appropriate for your situation, most of my apps are structured similarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to do it the first way, with each of your applications in its own module.  This configuration gives you the opportunity to develop each application separately while still allowing you to share resources between them.  It's also a lot easier to install, maintain and upgrade a single set of vendor files that are all in one place.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I'll do it this way (the first way) ! :)

Comment: If you have lots of applications to build modules for, you might consider [ZFTool](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool).  If you use it to create your modules, it will create your directory structures for you instead of having to create them manually, saving you time and typos.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is probably best if you have the same developer or developers maintaining all the apps, and if the apps would benefit from having access to shared resources.

Option 2  might be better if you have separate developers and/or if the apps have very little in common. For example, if they would be on different vhosts and do not share a common login.